# Showing that a set is a basis for a product topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider the space $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ of all functions $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$

For a function $f ∈ \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, a finite set $K ⊆ R$, and a real number $ε > 0$, define $U(f, K, ε) :=\{g ∈ \mathbb R^{\mathbb R}: |g(x) − f(x)| < ε$ for every $x ∈ K$}

Show that the family of all such sets is a basis for the product topology on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$.

> I must show that every open set in the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is the union of sets of the form $U(f,K,\epsilon)$. I do this by letting $V$ be an arbitrary non-empty open set in $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ and showing that for each $f\in V$ there are a finite $K_f\subseteq\Bbb R$ and an $\epsilon_f>0$ such that $f\in U(f,K_f,\epsilon_f)\subseteq V$.

> In order to do this, I have to know what the product topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is. Most likely it’s been defined in terms of a certain base $\mathscr{B}$ whose members are also defined partly in terms of finite subsets of $\Bbb R$. If that is the case, I know that there is a $B_f\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_f\subseteq V$, and I will have to show how to choose $K_f$ and $\epsilon_f$ so that $U(f,K_f,\epsilon_f)\subseteq B$.

I have these ideas but I cannot put them to term as a proof. Can anyone show me the proper proof to show the 2 axioms of a basis? Thank you.

Comment: Showing that any open set in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ is an union of sets of the form ... doesn't imply that ... is a basis.

Comment: To see this, closed intervals on $\mathbb{R}$ have this property but they don't form a basis of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You **don't** have to check the axioms for a basis! That's beside the point. **First** know what the product topology is. Then show that for any product-open $O$ and any $f \in O$ you can find some $K$ finite and $\varepsilon>0$ such that $U(f,K,\varepsilon) \subseteq O$ and you're done. That's all.

Comment: BTW, maybe give up the JOJO persona....

Answer (score 1):

Note that $U(g, K, \varepsilon) = \prod_{x\in K} (g(x)-\varepsilon, g(x)+\varepsilon) \times \prod_{x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus K} \mathbb{R}$ is a basic open set in the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$. Conversely, given any basic open set in the product topology, we can write it as a union of products of finite amount of open intervals and $\mathbb{R}$. Say, $K$ of them is this finite amount of open intervals, and $J_x$ for $x\in K$ are those intervals.

Take $g$ so that $g(x)$ is the center of $J_x$, and order non-increasingly $J_x$ by diameter as $J_{x_1}, J_{x_2}, ..., J_{x_n}$. Now you want to take $U(g, \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_i\}, \frac{1}{2}\text{diam}\ J_{x_i})$. Union of this sets is now the product of $J_x$ for $x\in K$ and $\mathbb{R}$ for $x\notin K$.

Comment: Here, you checked the second axiom of a basis only, right?

Comment: @CarlitoFernandez: That’s what the first part of the answer is trying to do, but it’s not quite right, since the $h$ that is defined need not even be in $U(g_1,K_1,\epsilon_1)\cap U(g_2,K_2,\epsilon_2)$. It’s also unnecessary: in order to show that these sets are a base for the product topology, it suffices to show that they are open in the product topology and that every non-empty open set in the product topology is a union of them.

Comment: Does the second part of the answer "Note that ..." prove the first axiom?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you're right, sorry